# Undetectable NaN when using quiet_NaN() and -Ofast

Tags: c++, nan

I am writing a classic `nanmean` function with OpenCV.
I try to emulate MatLab's `nanmean` by default behaviour (i.e. `nanmean` reduce on the first dimension).
I generate a matrix of random size which can be `CV_32F` or `CV_64F` with up to 4 channels. I fill it with random values following a uniform law.
Then I assign some values to Nan using `std::numerical_limits<float>` (if `CV_32F`, `double` otherwise) `:: quiet_NaN()`;

During the debugging step I was looking for an issue and I print the following:

```
T v = *it_src;
std::cout<<"v before: "<<v<<" "<<std::isnan(v)<<" "<<cvIsNaN(v)<<" "<<(v==v)<<" "<<" "<<std::isinf(v)<<" "<<((v+v)==v)<<std::endl;
```

T is template type, it can be either `float` or `double`, nothing else.

The output is:

```
v before: nan 0 0 1 0 1
```

So the value is "nan" but neither "std::isnan" nor "CvIsNan" can detect it.
The comparison feature from IEEE 754 (if v is a Nan then `v == v` should be false) failed (`v == v` return `true`). The only thing that works is the last check (`(v+v) == v`).

I have few questions:

- Simply why?
- Is where this issue come from and how to fix it?
- Can SIMD instructions also be concerned by this?

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Initialization
    int rows(theRNG().uniform(10,21)), cols(theRNG().uniform(10,21));
    int cn(theRNG().uniform(1, 5)); // [1, 5[ -> [1,4]
    
    Mat src(rows, cols, CV_32FC(cn));
    
    theRNG().fill(src, RNG::UNIFORM, 0, 10000);
    
    float ratio = theRNG().uniform(0.1f, 0.8f);
    int nb_points = saturate_cast<int>(src.total() * ratio);
    
    for(int i=0;i<nb_points;i++)
    {
     int x = theRNG().uniform(0, cols);
     int y = theRNG().uniform(0, rows);
     int z = theRNG().uniform(0, cn);
    
     src.ptr<float>(y,x)[z] = std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();
    
    }
    
    
    Mat dst = Mat::zeros(1, cols, src.type());
    
    // Computation (reduce mean with omition of the Nan value over the first axis).
    const size_t src_step1 = src.step1();
    
    for(int c=0; c<cols; c++)
    {
        // The default constructor of Scalar_ initialize the elements of the attribute "val" to 0.
        Scalar sum;
        Scalar_<int> cnt;
    
        const float* it_src = src.ptr<float>(0,c);
    
        for(int r=0; r<rows; r++, it_src+=src_step1)
            for(int i=0;i<cn;i++)
            {
                float v = it_src[i];
    
                std::cout<<"v before: "<<v<<" "<<std::isnan(v)<<" "<<cvIsNaN(v)<<" "<<(v==v)<<" "<<" "<<std::isinf(v)<<" "<<((v+v)==v)<<std::endl;
    
                if(!std::isnan(v)) // Failing
                {
                    sum[i]+= saturate_cast<double>(v);
                    cnt[i]++;
                }
            }
    
        for(int i=0; i<cn;i++)
        {
            float den = saturate_cast<float>(cnt[i]);
            if(den==0.f)
                den = 1.f;
            dst.ptr<float>(0, c)[i] = saturate_cast<float>(sum[i]) / den;
        }
    }

 return 0;

 }
```

Comment: Were any "dangerous" compilation options enabled such as `-ffast-math` or some related option?

Comment: "Minimal reproducible example" means it should be runnable: contains the `main`. Mininal: strip everything that is not needed to show thr problem you're having.

Comment: @harold no -ffast-math is not involve in this case.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I did added the main.

Comment: This seems to rely completely on opencv, so I can't run the example. Add opencv  as a tag to your question. Alternatively: print out the bit pattern of the strange number, and see what it means in IEEE 754.

Comment: To debug this, try printing the raw bits of `v`. This transfers an IEEE-754 `binary32` to a 32-bit unsigned integer: `uint32_t float_as_uint32 (float a) { uint32_t r; memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r); return r; }`.

Comment: @njuffa Ok I am doing this. If I well understand your idea, a printing in hexadecimal would also make sense.

Comment: Do you have quiet_NaN available for your platform, i.e. `std::numeric_limits<T>::has_quiet_NaN == true`?

Comment: @alagner yes I have quiet_NaN, I just check to be sure, It is confirmed.

Comment: @alagner the integer value for the nan is: 0x7fc00000.

Comment: @John_Sharp1318 `0x7fc00000` is a QNaN bit patttern. Make sure you set compiler switches for the strictest conformance with IEEE-754 floating-point  to get proper handling of NaNs. E.g. `icc -fp-model=strict`, `gcc -frounding-math -fsignaling-nans`.

Comment: @John_Sharp1318 For gcc, maybe also try adding `-fno-unsafe-math-optimizations`, as unsafe math optimizations could the turned on under the hood when using high optimization levels.

Comment: @njuffa I added the flags you suggested (I am on GCC), clean, and rebuild, the issue is still there.

Comment: I found the cause ... I was using the compilation flag -Ofast  ... when I remove OFast std::isnan works properly. ... why ? :(

Comment: Looking at the docs `-Ofast` turns on `-ffast-math`, which turns on `-ffinite-math-only`. This allows optimizations for floating point numbers that assume that arguments and results are not NaNs or +/- inf. At that point it seems pretty self-explanatory what most likely went wrong.

Comment: @John_Sharp1318 not sure if that's the case for every architecture, but from what I've briefly checked: `-ffast-math` increases possibilities of floating point functions to be inlined as they're not supposed to produce any side-effects with this switch on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mention in the comments that you were using `-Ofast`, and this was causing the issue. To understand why this is, we start by looking at the [GCC documentation for options that control optimizations](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.3.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html). Here it lists the following options that are turned on by `-Ofast`:

> It turns on -ffast-math, -fallow-store-data-races and the
> Fortran-specific -fstack-arrays, unless -fmax-stack-var-size is
> specified, and -fno-protect-parens.

For your case, looking at the description of `-ffast-math` seems relevant, as it sets the following set of options:

> Sets the options -fno-math-errno, -funsafe-math-optimizations,
> -ffinite-math-only, -fno-rounding-math, -fno-signaling-nans, -fcx-limited-range and -fexcess-precision=fast.

I didn't look at what each of all these options do, but `-ffinite-math-only` specifically seems like it would be incompatible with any program that cares about NaN or Inf, as it is documented as:

> Allow optimizations for floating-point arithmetic that assume that
> arguments and results are not NaNs or +-Infs.
>
> This option is not turned on by any -O option since **it can result in
> incorrect output for programs that depend on an exact implementation
> of IEEE or ISO rules/specifications for math functions**. It may,
> however, yield faster code for programs that do not require the
> guarantees of these specifications. [emphasis added]

Since your use case clearly includes detecting NaN, it would seem ill-advised to use this flag.

Simple example program that demonstrates the issue, when compile with GCC 11.3 using the `-Ofast` option ([Example on Godbolt because I don't have access to GCC right now](https://godbolt.org/z/YW639o3rf)). With `-O3` nothing is printed as expected, and with `-Ofast` it prints `Brought to you by -Ofast`:

```
#include <limits>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    auto value = std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();

    if(!std::isnan(value)) {
        std::puts("Brought to you by -Ofast");
    }
}
```